# Bayes rule for distribution functions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

For two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$, Bayes' theorem says:

\begin{equation*}
f_{X \mid Y=y}(x)=\frac{f_{Y \mid X=x}(y) f_{X}(x)}{f_{Y}(y)}
\end{equation*}

Now, if we do not know if $X$ and $Y$ are continuous, then we do not know if those densities above exist. Is there a way to write Bayes rule using distribution functions instead ? That would guarantee the rule for all random variables.

Comment: That depends on what "using distribution functions" means. We certainly have 
$$P(X\le x\mid Y\le y) = {P(Y\le y\mid X\le x)\,P(X\le x)\over P(Y\le y)}$$
i.e., 
$$F_{X\mid Y\le y}(x) = {F_{Y\mid X\le x}(y)\,F_X(x)\over F_Y(y)}$$
when the denominator is not zero, but how to *use* this is another question.

Comment: But how come we have $=$ instead of $\leq$ in the density case ?

Comment: @W.Volante: Have you heard of desintegration? If $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ is probability space $X$ and $Y$ random variables on $\Omega$ taking values on spaces $(S,\mathcal{S})$ and $(T,\mathcal{T})$, and $(S,\mathcal{S})$ is a nice space (a Polish space for example), then there exists a stochastic kernel $\mu:\mathcal{S}\times T\rightarrow[0,1]$ such that $P[X\in A| Y]=\mu(A,Y)$ ad form any positive integrable function $\phi(X,Y)$, $E[f(X,Y)]=\int_T\big(\int_S f(x,y)\mu(dx, y)\big)\nu_Y(dy)$ where $\nu_Y$ is the distribution of $Y$ (*to be continued*)

Comment: In your case, $X$ and $Y$ have values in $\mathbb{R}$ which with the usual topology is a nice space. Then, there is a function $\mu:(\mathscr{R}\times\mathbb{R})\rightarrow[0,1]$ such that if $F_Y(y)=P[Y\leq y]$, then almost surely $P[X\in A|Y=y]=\mu(A, y)$ and $P[X\in A,Y\in B]=\int_B\mu(A, y)\, F_Y(dy)$

Comment: Many probability and Statistic textbooks at the graduate level have presentations conditional expectation, regular conditional expectations and  disintegration. (Durret's Probability theory, Billingsley's Measure and Probability, Shao's Mathematical statistics, Feller's Probability Vol 2, etc)